# Multiply with Select MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, function

I want to create function in MySQL 5.6. This function will by multiply param by count players. But I don't know how I can do it.

I think like this, but it's not working as intended.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS do_it;

DELIMITER $$
 CREATE FUNCTION do_it (s INT) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    DECLARE k INT;
    SELECT COUNT(id_player) as allPlayers FROM players;
    SET k= allPlayers * s;
    RETURN k;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT do_it(2);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on "not good"? Do you get an error? The wrong value? No value at all?

Comment: Yes, I have error: "Not allowed to return a result set from a function"

Answer (score -1):

Rather do it like this way

```
DECLARE k INT;
declare multiplyvar int;
SELECT COUNT(id_player) into multiplyvar FROM players;
SET k = multiplyvar  * s;
RETURN k;
```

Comment: I have this error: Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Comment: See my edited answer. Try now. Also be wise while downvoting.

Comment: Now is: "Error SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/* CREATE FUNCTION do_it (s INT) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    DECLA' at line 26 */"

Comment: Not sure, if I go by your posted code then your posted `create function` looks fine to me. May be the error is in somewhere else. post the relevant code.